# Accessing a value defined in a typescript interface defintion

Tags: typescript, redux, interface, redux-saga, value-type

I'm new to typescript and have a question about it that I can't seem pose in a Googleable way.

Suppose I define this interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myField: "myValue"
}
```

I want to be able to write this line of code:

```
const value = MyInterface.myField; // expect value to equal "myValue"
```

This doesn't compile, but I'm wondering if there is some way to achieve this behavior. As the value of myField is defined at typescript compile time, I believe this should be possible. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:**

I guess I need to provide some more info. I am trying to reduce boilerplate and maintain type safety in a redux application by following this article:

https://medium.com/@resir014/a-type-safe-approach-to-redux-stores-in-typescript-6474e012b81e

I am also using redux-saga, and essentially I am trying to create a typesafe takeEvery.

Suppose I have two actions defined as interfaces, as suggested by the above article:

```
import { Action } from 'redux'

interface MyActionA extends Action {
  typeString: "MyActionA",
  payload: {
    // omitted
  }
}

interface MyActionB extends Action {
  typeString: "MyActionB",
  payload: {
    // omitted
  }
}

type MyActionBase =
  | MyActionA
  | MyActionB
```

Is there some valid way to write the following?:

```
function* typeSafeTakeEvery<ActionType extends MyActionBase>(saga: Function) {
  const typeString = ActionType.typeString; // <-- I don't know how to write this line
  yield takeEvery(typeString, function*(action: ActionType) {
    yield saga(action);
  });
}
```

For any given instantiation of this generic function, it knows the static type of ActionType (either MyActionA or MyActionB) and that it must have a field "typeString" with a "type" of either "MyActionA" or "MyActionB". I want to use this "type" as a constant value, and pass it to the actual takeEvery function.

Am I just way off base here?

Comment: Is this an interface you wrote? Maybe you need to rewrite it as an enum, which can compile as a value rather than a type.

Comment: Interfaces don't define values. They define types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the *value* `'myValue'` instead of the *type* `'myValue'`, you can use an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) instead of an `interface`:

```
enum MyEnum {
    myField = "myValue"
}

const value = MyEnum.myField;
```

#### Update

The reason that doesn't compile is because `ActionType` is what's called a *type* parameter, which is anything that is passed into `<...>` rather than `(...)`, which are known as *value* parameters, or more simply, just parameters.

Because it is a type and not a value, TypeScript removes its definition from the compiled JavaScript output, which is why you get an error that it's used as a value even though it's a type. So when the compiler runs, it leaves behind an undefined reference to `ActionType` that isn't declared anywhere in JavaScript.

Now, to solve your problem, I still recommend using an `enum`, and pass `actionType` as a value parameter, letting the `ActionType` type parameter infer its type and use it to declare a local type `MyAction` that extends `MyActionBase`, thus choosing `MyActionA` or `MyActionB` implicitly depending on the string literal passed.

```
import { Action } from 'redux'

enum MyActionType {
  MyActionA = 'MyActionA',
  MyActionB = 'MyActionB'
}

interface MyActionA extends Action {
  typeString: MyActionType.MyActionA,
  payload: {
    // omitted
  }
}

interface MyActionB extends Action {
  typeString: MyActionType.MyActionB,
  payload: {
    // omitted
  }
}

type MyActionBase =
  | MyActionA
  | MyActionB

function* typeSafeTakeEvery<ActionType extends MyActionType>(actionType: ActionType, saga: Function) {
  type MyAction = MyActionBase & { typeString: ActionType }

  yield takeEvery(actionType, function*(action: MyAction) {
    yield saga(action);
  });
}

// Usage

typeSafeTakeEvery(MyActionType.MyActionA, ...)
```

Comment: Oh that's cool. Thank you! Was heading entirely the wrong way.

Comment: You weren't actually far off. Just remember that when you need to get stricter type enforcement based on a value, look for techniques that use implicit type inference and feel free to declare local types if you need to. They're free and it doesn't bloat your JavaScript at all!